# What is the most efficient way for a beginner to improve his posture?

Tags: jeet-kune-do

I only started Jeet Kune Do about two months ago. Everytime I am coming to the class, I find that my posture is still not correct even for the simplest strikes such as a straight lead.

Is there anything I can do to make sure that I train with the correct posture.

I tried to train in front of a mirror but it seems that everytime I go to the class, there is something I did not pay attention enough such as the front arm not being directed towards the opponent or the shoulder line not being at 45 degrees.

It seems that some other students are learning much quicker, what should I focus on to improve ?

Comment: You will spend years learning the correct posture and positions. This is perfectly normal.

Comment: @slugster: so should I just not try to force it and just continue practicing in front of a mirror until I get it ? Or is there anything I can do to progress faster ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem to be asking about "posture" in the narrow sense, but rather how to improve your entire body positioning for all techniques. This is the majority of martial arts practice. Your best bet for improving body position for JKD techniques is to make sure you're strong and mobile enough to do all the postures correctly, and to go to class as much as possible. Expert external feedback is really key for improving skill.

If you're two months in, it's normal to be as coordinated as a drugged panda trying to tap-dance. Don't sweat it. Go to class a lot, do some strength training once a week or so, and be patient.

Comment: Thanks, will follow  your advice. Unfortunately there are only two classes per week where I am going, so I cannot go more often than this.

Comment: @BlueTrin Perhaps yoga and barbell training could fill in the gaps, to ensure that you have the requisite strength and mobility.

Comment: I started strength training and Pilates. Pilates surprisingly help alot with any moves involving your core (it is most noticeable on hooks)

Answer (score 2):

Stretch a lot. Then just practice everything you are taught literally two thousand times, slowly. To start off, do a movement but stop after a centimeter. Check you are in the right position, are your hips and shoulders facing the correct way, should you be twisting, where should you hand be, what position should you feet be in, should your back be extended, every single thing. If you do not remember every thing, ask your teacher to hold techniques and write down his positioning.

Move another centimeter, check again. After 50 times, stop the technique once half way through, check it, then finish it, then check it. I would say after 500 very slow techniques, start to speed it up. This may seem boring but you should be dedicated. Some people naturally learn quicker, but someone's natural ability will never beat dedicated training. How are you for spare time? When i got serious with martial arts i would go to a woods somewhere every morning and train for 3 hours.

Do not be worried about moving slowly, if you technique is slow yet perfectly executed, your teacher will notice. Also if attention to detail is a problem, execute a movement with your teacher watching, write down everything he says is wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, to answer your question: I try to practice in front of a mirror or on a punching bag outside of classes about 5 times a week for 1 hour. Cannot do more with my current job as I also have to do strength training and stretching.

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult for many of us to concentrate on distinctly different aspects of a movement or stance at the same time, so first of all don't get frustrated!

It sounds like to me at the core of your question is how to "find your center", or how to achieve good balance across stances.

There is a natural tendency in many students to lean forward, particularly when executing a hand technique such as a straight punch or jab.  I'm not sure if this is just human instinct or the conditioning of the media we consume.

Simply being aware of it will help you correct your stances over time.  The more you achieve balanced stances the more natural will be your inclination to achieve a balanced stance.

One thing that may help you is to strengthen your legs by doing plenty of squats and holding squats while concentrating on keeping your back straight and sitting back on your heels.

Almost all stances require a bent leg supporting body weight to achieve balance.  Leaning forward relieves some of the tension on the quads, so you need to train your muscles and your mind to embrace the physical effort of holding a balanced stance.

Answer (score 2):

A digital camera can be good for this. Film yourself doing the movement, then watch the footage while the feel of it is still fresh in your mind. Even better, if you have a large TV near where you train, watch yourself doing the movement. That's probably the best way to be able to see, say, a side view, as you're moving.

Comment: Be prepared for this self-observation to be de-moralizing as your self-image and corresponding image of yourself doing the movements contrasts sharply with what you see on the screen.  Anytime you think "Wow, I sure am getting good" try filming yourself.

Comment: Oi... I videotaped a capoeira roda that I was participating in. I was clumsy. I was slow. And I looked chunky. That said, the camera method helped me immensely with my handstands and broken cartwheels.